# Simple XML - Two different root elements

Tags: java, simple-framework

my Problem is that i have to parse a xml-document that can have two different root xml-tags.

Variant 1:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<success>
success...
</success>
```

Variant 2:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<error>
error...
</error>
```

I know there is the annotation `@ElementUnion()`, but as far as i understand it only works for non-root tags.

Some more information:

I'm working with retrofit and consume an api and use simple-xml to parse the xml-document.

It would be great if someone has a solution or a workaround.

The only idea i have is to call the api, catch the exception and retry with the other model for variant 2.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please [edit] your post to show the Java code.

Comment: @JimGarrison I only want to know if it is possible to parse an xml-document with two possible root elements with the simple-xml-framework (http://simple.sourceforge.net/home.php). I dont't need an actual implementation.

Comment: From the doc it looks like you'll have to detect the expected class somehow before trying to deserialize.  That's why it's called "Simple".

Comment: As far as I know, when you have different root elements, you literally have different xml document types. One way around this would be to create two parsers, one for success documents, and another for errors. A better solution would be to wrap both success and error elements within a common root element, but this would only be an option if you have control over creating the xml documents in the first place.

Comment: @JimGarrison Unfortunately I expected this answer.
Unhappily I don't have control over the server.
Maybe some workarounds? Because the only workaround I found so far is to consume the api twice with the models for variant 1/2 and wait which one will throw an exception. Not a very elegant solution.

Comment: I believe @MaanooAk's answer is going to be the best you can do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `Persister.validate`. It takes the same arguments as the `Persister.read` and returns simple true or false if the passed class can be parsed.

This is the best possible way using the API, you could also manually detect the class by reading the first two lines of the xml (in your example) but in more complicated structures you need to use the 'validate'.

Comment: The only problem: I'm using retrofit and don't have direct access or control over the deserialization-process. The callback to me, in which I could get the response as string and validate the xml (...) isn't called, because before that the exception is thrown. Maybe I can solve this by providing my own `Converter`.

Comment: Okay I found a solution. If i don't pass in a `Converter` and change the return type to `RequestBody`, I can extract the body and parse it myself with your solution.

Comment: The converter is also simple to make, the simple converter it's only around 40 lines of code: https://github.com/square/retrofit/blob/master/retrofit-converters/simplexml/src/main/java/retrofit2/converter/simplexml/SimpleXmlResponseBodyConverter.java

Comment: Ohhhh, then I think I will take a second look on this approach.